# Why is my Laravel 8.0 session not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Session is working fine if I am printing in the `UserSession` function but it's not working on the view page.

//controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class UserSession extends Controller
{
  public function loginSession(Request $req)
  {
    $data = $req->input();
    $req->session()->put('username',$data['username']);
    return redirect("profile");
  }
}
```

//view

```
<p>Hello, {{session('username')}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Session::put('username',$data['username']);
```

instead

```
$req->session()->put('username',$data['username']);
```

then call in blade file

```
<p>Hello, {{session('username')}}</p>
```

Comment: I tried doing it Session::put('username',$data['username'])     But it's not working

Comment: do dd($data['username']) to see data comes in $data['username'] or  not? before this line Session::put('username',$data['username']);

Comment: or do Session::put('username',$req->username);

Comment: After using  dd($data['username']), I can see the username but still username is not coming on view file.

Comment: use this $req->session()->put('username',$data['username']);
    $req->session()->save();

Answer (score 0):

call `save()` after putting value in session.

```php
public function loginSession(Request $req)
{
    $data = $req->input();
    $req->session()->put('username',$data['username']);
    $req->session()->save();
    return redirect("profile");
}
```